# how to pass variable values to controller

Tags: cakephp

```
<div id="dsel1" style="text-align:center;width:800px;"></div><br>

<br>
<span id="wtf"></span>

<script type="text/javascript">


  var calendarPicker1 = $("#dsel1").calendarPicker({
    monthNames:["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
    dayNames: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],

    callback:function(cal) {
        var date=cal.currentDate;
      alert(date);
      $("#wtf").html("Selected date: " + cal.currentDate);
    }});
</script>
```

here this code displays date from datepicker , it works fine but i have to pass the date variable value to profiles controller, index action with this one id and the date cariable

Comment: can you create fiddle please

Comment: Probably you are asking `How to pass javascript variable to PHP?` If it is, then there lots of questions already on SO with answers..

Answer (score 0):

```
// javascript redirect
window.location = '/profiles/index?id=123&date=2014-05-03'

// ProfilesController
public function index() {
    $id = $this->request->query['id'];
    $date = $this->request->query['date'];
}
```

OR if you want to stay on the same page use ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/profiles/index',
    data:{id:123, date:'2014-05-03'},
    type:'POST',
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // do something
    }
})

// ProfilesController
public function index() {
    if($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $id = $this->request->data['id'];
        $date = $this->request->data['date'];
        // do something
    }
}
```